# dynamically filling <ul></ul> in javascript and php

Tags: php, jquery, post, html-lists

I have the following element which is empty:

```
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" id="contributionList2" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
</ul>
</div>
```

I also have a javascript function that has an array called "arrayer" that I'm trying to post to a php script:

```
for(var i=0;i<arrayer.length;i++){
    $.post('rpc4.php', {'test': arrayer[i] }, function(data){
        $('#contributionList2').append(data);
    });
}
```

The javascript code successfully posts the array to the file rpc4.php:

```
<?php
$myvar = $_POST['test'];
echo '<li>'.$myvar.'</li>';
?>
```

But when I try to fill the listview "contributionList2" with all of the array elements, it simply displays each one for a second and then replaces it with the next element in the array rather than showing them all in the listview. How can I show all elements from teh array in the listview at once when the javascript code is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `html()` to `append()`.

`html()` will replace the content of your `<ul>` with each pass through your loop; but you want the stuff to accumulate. `append()` will stuff the new element as the last child of your `<ul>`.

However, this is not the best way; unless you have a very good reason for it, it would be better if you move your loop serverside: `join()` your `arrayer`, post it as a parameter to your PHP script, then `explode()` it in PHP and generate everything in one go.

Comment: Great that works. But now it seems to list them all in the same <li> tag. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Can you update your question so we can see what exactly you did?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see why it would list everything in a same `<li>`. Can you use Developer Tools or Firebug to check the structure of your `<ul>`?